# Initiation call Django class based view.

Tags: python, django

This is more of a conceptual question. While learning the Django class-based view, I am wondering if it is possible to make a call to a Django view as an initiation call. I mean, after the first call, the following calls from the templates can share the instance variables created by the first one. This avoids passing variables back and forth between the template and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Django views are specifically designed to *prevent* this. It would be a very bad idea; any instance variables set would be shared by *all* future users of that process, leading to potential information leakage and other thread-safety bugs.

If you want to store information between requests, use the session.

Comment: I really like your answer. Very straightforward for a beginner like me.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.